# Build a common authentication service based on oAuth or ACS?

Tags: authentication, azure, oauth, acs

I have several websites, some are ASP.NET MVC based (deployed on Azure) and some PHP based (deployed on Linux machines).
I want to provide all website a common authentication (or even authorization), allowing the user to signup directly (using my private registration) or via external identity provider (google/live/facebook).

The plan is to build that common authentication in .NET/MVC and deploy it to Azure.

As I understand there are two alternatives:
1. Building oAuth(2?) server
or 
2. Building a authentication service based on Azure' ACS

Any guidelines what to choose?
Which one more mature?
which one allows better integration with mixed platforms (.net and PHP)
Any best practices, reference to sample code etc?
(By the way, i am not a security expert)

Thanks,
Yaron

Answer (score 1):

Do take a look at Thinktecture Identity Server (https://github.com/thinktecture). It is open source project built by security experts and does everything you're trying to accomplish and then some more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very rich tutorial showing how to do that with ADFS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx

Comment: I already saw this one, my main concern is integration with PHP site. Is the ACS preferable over oAuth?